# How to retrieve all google maps rectangles in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

When I initiate the map I have this listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
console.log('value of e');
console.log(e);
polyArray.push(e);

if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
    // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
}
setMapClickEvent(e.overlay, e.type);
setSelection(e.overlay);
```

});

Immediatly after this declaration I loop through the current rectangles that should be automatically drawn on the map. This is the code:

```
_.each($scope.currentRactangles, function(arr) {
new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#002288',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#333322',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    editable: true,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(arr.upper_lat, arr.upper_lng),
        new google.maps.LatLng(arr.lower_lat, arr.lower_lng)
    )
});
```

});

Now, when map is loaded, the existing rectangles (fetched from database) are drawn on the map.
However, the listener never gets triggered.
If I manually draw a rectangle, the I can see in the console "value of e" and the event itself.
My question is: is it possible to trigger the listener when drawing rectangles programmatically? 
All this because when I store the rectangles in database, I will store stuff inside the array "polyArray". Which only contains rectangles created manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution was about storing in the array the newly created rectangles. Basically this snippet:

```
var tmprect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                    strokeColor: '#002288',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: '#333322',
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    map: map,
                    editable: true,
                    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(arr.upper_lat, arr.upper_lng),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(arr.lower_lat, arr.lower_lng)
                    )
                });
                var newrect = {};
                newrect.type = 'rectangle';
                newrect.overlay = tmprect;
                polyArray.push(newrect);
```

Even if the rectangles from database didn't generated an event they are now inside the same array that will also contain the rectangles manually drawn. That was enough for me as I only needed a way to store rectangles both from user and the automatically generated.